# how to apply CSS for @Html.DisplayFor?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying apply css to DisplayFor. I could not. How to do that?

```
 MeetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel = meetingQuestionses[0].question_text

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, new { @class = "control-label mandatory" })
```

If I use `DisplayFor`. It shows like no ***bold***
[image]

If I use `LableFor`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisplayFor` is used as a templating system. If you are not using a template, you should probably stick with wrapping it in some html tags.

Comment: But LableFor is showing propertyname not actual value of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload of the method that allows for an HTML Attributes anonymous object [see the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can create an overload yourself if you want for that though, or just use `LabelFor` as you discovered.

However, if you do use `LabelFor`, be wary that the signature for the method is different than all other extension methods. The first string parameter is always the identifier of the corresponding `<input>` element. It will also display that text if there is not the second string parameter, but that will get truncated if there is a "." in your text.

To solve this issue, and maintain a consistent look for my code, I created the `@Html.Span()` extension method like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to create an HTML Span node.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="displayText">The Text to display as the value.</param>
/// <param name="expression">A corresponding Control that this Span is "for".</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains HTML attributes to set for this Span.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a Span element that will display the given text.</returns>
/// <remarks>Using Html.Label will take the first string parameter as the name of the input the label is "for".
/// To display text, you need to use the second string parameter, which is contrary to every other method they use.
/// This method will instead create a span tag with the appropriate text being displayed.</remarks>
public static MvcHtmlString Span(this HtmlHelper html, string displayText, string expression, object htmlAttributes) {
    TagBuilder spanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression)) {
        spanBuilder.MergeAttribute("for", expression);
    }

    if (htmlAttributes != null) {
        RouteValueDictionary attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> attr in attributes) {
            spanBuilder.MergeAttribute(attr.Key, attr.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    spanBuilder.SetInnerText(displayText);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(spanBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

I also have a series of similar overloads (each with fewer parameters) for the method that all call into this method.